# Facebook comment widget shares comments across Posts

Tags: facebook

I finally set up FB comment widget on my blog. But I noticed that comments posted on one blog posts are available on another blog post also. This does not look good. I want to restrict FB comments pertaining to one blog post only to that post and not have them available all over the post. By and large I am looking for comment mechanism like the one used by Techcrunch.

Is there any setting I could do for this?
I am not posting my Blog URL as I might be violating StackOver flow policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/, each data-href needs to be unique for the comments plug-in to have each plug-in have their own comments.